# How to call this.remote inside .then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, intern

If I have something like

```
return this.remote
    .findByXpath('xpath to open menu').click().end()
    .then(function() {
        // check menu items
        ...
        return this.remote
            .findByXpath('xpath to close menu').click.end()
    });
```

It gives me an ECONNREFUSED error. How do I nest calls with the this.remote Command object?

Comment: just save dynamic `this` to more static variable in outer scope: `var that = this;` and use `that` inside.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea how to word my question.. sorry!